# mongodb: Select the latest entry in an embedded array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following data of Items with a price history:

```
{
  item: "Item A",
  priceHistory: [
    {
      date: ISODate("2021-04-01T08:32:45.561Z"),
      value: 100
    },
    {
      date: ISODate("2021-04-02T08:32:45.561Z"),
      value: 200
    },
    {
      date: ISODate("2021-04-04T08:32:45.561Z"),
      value: 400
    },
    {
      date: ISODate("2021-04-03T08:32:45.561Z"),
      value: 300
    },
  ]
},{
  item: "Item B",
  priceHistory: [
    {
      date: ISODate("2021-04-01T08:32:45.561Z"),
      value: 1
    }
  ]
}, ...
```

Note that the `priceHistory` field is **not** sorted.

I want to find the latest price for each item:

```
{
  item: "Item A",
  price: 400
},{
  item: "Item B",
  price: 1
}, ...
```

Now I'm struggling to select the LATEST entry of the `priceHistory`

#### What I tried already

- I know that I can use `{ $unwind: "$priceHistory" }` to get a result for each entry in `priceHistory`.
- With `$max: "$priceHistory.date"` I can find the latest `date`
- I know that since MongoDB 4.4 there is `$last` to get the last item in an array -> not useful here since items are not in order

But I struggle to bring it all together.

---

On a side note, maybe the problem lies within the data model itself? Would it make sense to segregate price history into its own collection, and only store the latest price on the item itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/-LQPcTn_-Aj

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$priceHistory" }, // unwind to individual documents
  { $sort: { "priceHistory.date": -1 } }, // sort by priceHistory.date to get max date at the top (descending)
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id", // group by id back and get priceHistory sorted in descending order by date
      price: { $first: "$priceHistory.value" }, // get the first price which is for max date record
      item: { $first: "$item"}
    }
  }
])
```